# MySQL column name with singl UNIQUE constraint indicator

Tags: mysql, information-schema

I need a query which would (for given table name) show a list of columns with indicator if there exists UNIQUE constraint for this column BUT only if this column is SINGLE COLUMN constraint, NOT if this column is part of multiple column constraint.

For example for this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `prices` (
  `priceId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `motorcycleId` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `priceDatum` DATE NOT NULL,
  `price` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`priceId`),
  INDEX `price_motorcycleId_fk_idx` (`motorcycleId` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `priceId_UNIQUE` (`priceId` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `price_UNIQUE` (`motorcycleId` ASC, `priceDatum` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `price_motorcycleId_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`motorcycleId`)
    REFERENCES `motorcycles` (`motorcycleId`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

this query should give:

```
COLUMN      |UNIQUE
============+======
priceId     |  Y
motorcycleId|  N    <-- should not be shown as UNIQUE since not single constraint
priceDatum  |  N    <-- should not be shown as UNIQUE since not single constraint
price       |  N
```

Comment: Side note, the unique constraint is redundant on priceId, since the primary key is unique by definition.

Comment: Thanks @Michael-sqlbot for your note, it is valuable. I know that this is redundant, but I put it here just for the sake of example. I was discussing it recently (look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493487/mysql-primary-key-vs-unique-constraints)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
SELECT c.COLUMN_NAME,
        IF((SELECT COUNT(k2.COLUMN_NAME)
          FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k1
          JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k2 
               ON (k1.CONSTRAINT_NAME=k2.CONSTRAINT_NAME
               AND k1.TABLE_NAME=k2.TABLE_NAME
               AND k1.TABLE_SCHEMA=k2.TABLE_SCHEMA)
          JOIN information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
               ON (k2.CONSTRAINT_NAME=tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
               AND k2.TABLE_NAME=tc.TABLE_NAME
               AND k2.TABLE_SCHEMA=tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
               AND tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE='UNIQUE')
         WHERE k1.COLUMN_NAME=c.COLUMN_NAME
           AND k1.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME)=1,'Y','N') AS `UNIQUE`
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS c
  LEFT JOIN information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k
   ON (k.TABLE_SCHEMA=c.TABLE_SCHEMA
       AND k.TABLE_NAME=c.TABLE_NAME
       AND k.COLUMN_NAME=c.COLUMN_NAME
       AND k.POSITION_IN_UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT IS NOT NULL)
 WHERE c.TABLE_NAME='prices'
 ORDER BY c.ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not just check if such a constraint exists, but also if that constraint has only one column. So the count for that constraint in KEY_COLUMN_USAGE should be 1.

I can't test it at the moment, but it should look something like this to get the columns that have such a constraint. You can do a similar thing in the subquery, or just left join this query on the list of all columns and check: If a record exists, there is a unique single column constraint, otherwise there isn't.

```
select
  k.COLUMN_NAME 
from 
  information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE k
  join information_schema.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS tc
    on k.TABLE_SCHEMA = tc.TABLE_SCHEMA
      and k.TABLE_NAME = tc.TABLE_NAME
      and k.CONSTRAINT_NAME = tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME
where
  k.TABLE_NAME = 'prices'
  and tc.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'UNIQUE'
group by
  k.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG,
  k.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA,
  k.CONSTRAINT_NAME
having
  count(*) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks @GolezTrol for your effort. I tried almost the same thing with HAVING COUNT(*)=1 but did not succeed. Your subquery does not work. Here is the SQLFiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cbe483/17 how I did it, but I'm not sure if it is the best approach. Still think that this could be done with GROUP BY HAVING and reducing inner SELECT for one JOIN.