# how costly is it to add unique constraint on all columns mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

In general, I see two simple ways of ensuring that there are no duplicate rows in a table.

1. Add a UNIQUE constraint on all columns of the table (in my case 3)
2. Create a primary key id which is a hash of the other columns

The latter is going to be more work to implement. Does it offer performance improvements comparing an int primary key as opposed to 3 columns? Or does mysql internally already use some sort of hash on the columns when it checks uniqueness?

EDIT: the types of the columns are int(11), int(11), and datetime(6)

Comment: Create a unique index on the columns. Internally, MySQL stores the index as a B-tree.

Comment: What will the resulting complexity be? Will it be on the same order as primary key id?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL PRIMARY KEY vs UNIQUE constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493487/mysql-primary-key-vs-unique-constraints)

Comment: Bear in mind that comparing hashes (certainly one that fits in an int) tells you when the two inputs are definitely *different* but does not tell you that two inputs are the *same*. Therefore, your two proposals do two different things so you need to consider what you're actually trying to enforce.

Comment: The most important piece of information is usually the data types and sizes of the three columns in question.  What are they?

Answer (score 4):

The number of bytes in an index is limited.  For instance, InnoDB limits index to 767 bytes (as explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html)).  So, depending on your row, you may not be able to define a unique index or primary key on all the columns.

Implementing a hash has two short-comings:

- Hashes have collisions.  So, the probability may be very small (depending on the hash algorithm), but it does exist.
- You need to add the hash value, which typically means using a trigger.

This is all possible -- as are insert/update triggers to guarantee the uniqueness.

My guess, though, is that you don't need a unique constraint on *all* columns.  Some subset is probably reasonable to guarantee uniqueness.  And if they are unique, the whole row is unique.

Comment: I would be handling the hash value through code w/o using a trigger and unfortunately in this case I need all three columns (only three though) to guarantee uniqueness. Would you still recommend unique constraint?

Comment: @curiousgeorge . . . If you need to guarantee uniqueness on three columns, then create a unique constraint.